# Social Login in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am stuck with Social login (Facebook, Google and twitter) through Phonegap.
I have googled and found so many solutions, but they don't work on either platform (i.e: android or iOS).
Does any one have implemented social login in his/her app using phonegap?

If any one could provide me the running code, that would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sabir

Comment: What plugin(s) did you use? What have you tried? What social plattform do you want to use? Facebook? Google? Twitter? A good starting point is propbably Christophe Coenraets blog: http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/.

Comment: I have used that one also but unable to success.

Comment: Please post your code. Your question is to broad and it's unlikely that you will get an helpful answer. You are asking for a working example and as you already stated - there are tons out there. So pick one you think is most promising and try to get that up and running by posting your code.

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 2):

I know it's probably late to answer your particular question but I have had the same issue - all of the current (September 2016) scripts, snippets and libraries for social login in PhoneGap/Cordova that I have tried did not work so I made some simple functions from scratch which may still be useful to people ending up here. You can use them to log the user in with LinkedIn, Facebook and Google(+). I have also made some simple functions that retrieve some basic user information from the access token that is returned by logging the user in with the given network. You can examine the functions but they usually save the token or/and the user data to localStorage for later usage. They have been tested in September 2016 and work perfectly. I hope that this would help other people who also land on failing snippets around the web.

You can just insert the code and use the functions whenever you want. It requires jQuery and PhoneGap's InAppBrowser (besides having made apps/clients in the social media in order to fill the app id and app secret).

As a side note, it is not the best move to store the client secret directly in the PhoneGap application as the source can be viewed by malevolent people.

The code can be refactored at many places, so feel free to do that, but it does the trick. You may also have to handle cases where the user cancels the login process.

```html
var facebookLogin = function(appId, appSecret, successCb,errCb) {


  /*$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + appId + "&client_secret=" +appSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials", function(res) {
        if (res.indexOf("access_token=") !== -1) {
              successCb(res.replace("access_token=", "").trim());
        }
        else {
          errCb(res);
        }


  })
  */


  var ref = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&response_type=token&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+"http://anyurlhere.com", "_blank", "location=no");
  ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(evt) {


    if (evt.url.indexOf("anyurlhere.com") !== -1) {
      if (evt.url.indexOf("#access_token") !== -1) {
          localStorage.fbToken = evt.url.split("#access_token=")[1];
          ref.close();
          ref.addEventListener("exit", function() {
                successCb(localStorage.fbToken);
          })
      }


    }
  })

}

var linkedinLogin = function(appId,appSecret,successCb,errCb) {

  var ref = window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+(encodeURI("http://anyurlhere.com"))+"&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile", "_blank", "location=no");
  ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(evt) {

    if (evt.url.indexOf("anyurlhere.com") !== -1) {
      if (evt.url.indexOf("code=") !== -1) {
        var code = evt.url.split("code=")[1];
        code = code.split("&")[0];

        //TODO:  get actual token to access user profile
        $.post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", {"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code": code, "redirect_uri":encodeURI("http://anyurlhere.com"), "client_id":appId,"client_secret":appSecret}, function(data) {
          for (key in data) {
            if (key == 'access_token') {

              localStorage.linkedinToken = data[key];
              ref.close();
              ref.addEventListener("exit", function() {
                successCb(localStorage.linkedinToken);
              })
            }


          }
        })

      }

    }
  })

}

var googleLogin = function(appId, appSecret, successCb, errCb) {

  var ref = window.open("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=token&client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri="+encodeURI("http://anyurlhere.com")+"&scope="+encodeURIComponent("email profile")+"&state=profile", "_blank", "location=no");
  ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(evt) {
    if (evt.url.indexOf("anyurlhere.com") !== -1) {

      if (evt.url.indexOf("access_token=") !== -1) {
        var accessToken = evt.url.split("access_token=")[1];
        accessToken = accessToken.split("&")[0];

        localStorage.gToken = accessToken;

        ref.close();
        ref.addEventListener("exit", function() {
            successCb(localStorage.gToken);
        })
      }
    }
  })

}

var getGoogleInfo = function(successCb, errCb) {
  //get basic user profile
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + localStorage.gToken, function(userInfo) {
      successCb(userInfo);
    })
}

var getFacebookInfo = function(successCb, errCb) {
  //get basic user profile-name
  $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name,picture&access_token=" + localStorage.fbToken, function(userInfo) {



    var myInfo = {};
    if (userInfo.name) {
          myInfo.name = userInfo.name;
    }
    if (userInfo.email) {
      myInfo.email = userinfo.email;
    }

    if (userInfo.picture) {
      myInfo.picture = userInfo.picture.data.url;
    }

    localStorage.myInfo = JSON.stringify(myInfo);
      successCb(myInfo);
    // localStorage.myInfo = myInfo;
  })
}

//get basic data for linked in

var getLinkedinInfo = function(successCb, errCb) {

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.linkedinToken
      },
      success: function(userInfo) {



        var myInfo = {};
        if (userInfo.firstName && userInfo.lastName) {
            myInfo.name = userInfo.firstName + " " + userInfo.lastName;

        }
        if (userInfo.headline) {
          myInfo.linkedinHeadline = userInfo.headline;

        }
        localStorage.myInfo = JSON.stringify(myInfo);

        successCb(myInfo);

      },
      fail: function(err) {
        alert(err);
        for (key in err) {
          alert(key);
          alert(err[key]);
        }
      }


  })



}

//example of logging in the user with Google + and getting his/her data

googleLogin("93-54932-423-fkfew.apps.googleusercontent.com", "", function(accessToken) {
        getGoogleInfo(function(userInfo) {

          var myInfo = {};
          alert(userInfo.name);
          if (userInfo.email) {
                    myInfo.email = userInfo.email;
          }
          if (userInfo.name) {
              myInfo.name = userInfo.name;
          }
          if (userInfo.given_name) {
              myInfo.firstName = userInfo.given_name;
          }
          if (userInfo.familyName) {
                      myInfo.familyName = userInfo.family_name;
          }
          if (userInfo.picture) {
                      myInfo.picture = userInfo.picture;
          }
```

Comment: what should be the `http://anyurlhere.com`? i have write `http://eaimanshoshi.com` here. but it is not working. I have set  the url as redirect_url in google console. in the process of redirection it says that `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: Hey, some time passed since I wrote this but anyurlhere.com can be whatever you want, the trick is simply to redirect the user to an endpoint in order to capture the key from the URL, then you close the In-App Browser with the opened page, so you can choose an arbitrary URL that you own. On that page, you do not have to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I spend some time on your code and i have figured it out and solved my problem :P thanks for you reply. your answer was really helpful.

Comment: And I have also implemented twitter login in your code